# Update/Replace output text onClick - replaceNodes - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, replace

I have a form that takes information and outputs it in a div if its complete. If the form is not complete, output is error messages relating to the specific field which needs correcting. The error messages/output update as information is changed and the button is clicked.

Currently valid output will update as it changes, but going between valid output and error messages, the two sets of text both appear on the page, and then remain there until I refresh the page. Here's the code:

```
   /*
    Project 1 - AJAX 2015
    2/14/15
    Mitch Gundrum
 */

/*
    Function to create input and HTML elements,
    Create output nodes; output div
 */

function init() {
//Output Div
    var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.id = "output";
//Name
    var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
        name.type = "text";
//Address
    var address = document.getElementById("address").value;
        address.type = "text";
    var city = document.getElementById("city").value;
        city.type = "text";
    var state = document.getElementById("state");
        state.type = "text";
    var index = state.selectedIndex;
        var fullState = state.options[index];
    var zip = document.getElementById("zip").value;
        zip.type = "text";
//Email
    var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
        email.type = "text";
//Phone Number
    var areaCode = document.getElementById("areaCode").value;
        areaCode.type = "text";
    var prefix = document.getElementById("prefix").value;
        prefix.type = "text";
    var suffix = document.getElementById("suffix").value;
        suffix.type = "text";
//Gender
    var gender = document.getElementsByName("gender");
    var genderChoice = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < gender.length; i++) {
            if (gender[i].checked) {
                genderChoice += gender[i].value;
            }
        }
//Previous Courses
    var courses = document.getElementsByName("courses");
        var courseChoice = "";
        for (var e = 0; e < courses.length; e++) {
            if (courses[e].checked) {
                courseChoice += courses[e].value + ", ";
            }
        }
//Call Validate form method; pass all elements
    validateForm(div, name, address, city, fullState, zip,
        email, areaCode, prefix, suffix, genderChoice,
        courseChoice);
}

//Check all elements for null
function validateForm(div, name, address, city, fullState, zip,
                      email, areaCode, prefix, suffix, genderChoice,
                      courseChoice) {

    var RUN_OUTPUT = 1;

    function br() {
        return document.createElement('br');
    }

    if (name == null || name == "") {
        var nameError = "Name is not valid";
        var printNameError = document.createTextNode(nameError);
        var nameLabel = document.getElementById("nameError");
            nameLabel.appendChild(printNameError);
        RUN_OUTPUT = 0;
    }
    if (email == null || email == "") {
        var emailError = "Email is not valid";
        var printEmailError = document.createTextNode(emailError);
        var emailLabel = document.getElementById("emailError");
            emailLabel.appendChild(printEmailError);
        RUN_OUTPUT = 0;
    }
    if (areaCode == null || areaCode == "" || prefix == null || prefix == "" || suffix == null || suffix == "") {
        var phoneError = "Area Code is not valid";
        var printPhoneError = document.createTextNode(phoneError);
        var phoneLabel = document.getElementById("phoneError");
            phoneLabel.appendChild(printPhoneError);
        RUN_OUTPUT = 0;
    }
    if (address == null || address == "") {
        var addressError = "Address is not valid";
        var printAddressError = document.createTextNode(addressError);
        var addressLabel = document.getElementById("addressError");
            addressLabel.appendChild(printAddressError);
        RUN_OUTPUT = 0;
    }
    if (city == null || city == "") {
        var cityError = "City is not valid";
        var printCityError = document.createTextNode(cityError);
        var cityLabel = document.getElementById("cityError");
            cityLabel.appendChild(printCityError);
        RUN_OUTPUT = 0;
    }
    if (fullState == null || fullState == "") {
        var stateError = "State is not valid";
        var printStateError = document.createTextNode(stateError);
        var stateLabel = document.getElementById("stateError");
            stateLabel.appendChild(printStateError);
        RUN_OUTPUT = 0;
    }
    if (zip == null || zip == "") {
        var zipError = "Zip is not valid";
        var printZipError = document.createTextNode(zipError);
        var zipLabel = document.getElementById("zipError");
            zipLabel.appendChild(printZipError);
        RUN_OUTPUT = 0;
    }
    if (genderChoice == null || genderChoice == "") {
        var genderError = "Gender is not valid";
        var printGenderError = document.createTextNode(genderError);
        var genderLabel = document.getElementById("genderError");
            genderLabel.appendChild(printGenderError);
        RUN_OUTPUT = 0;
    }
    if (courseChoice == null || courseChoice == "") {
        var courseError = "No Courses!";
        var printCourseError = document.createTextNode(courseError);
        var courseLabel = document.getElementById("courseError");
            courseLabel.appendChild(printCourseError);
        RUN_OUTPUT = 0;
    }

    if (Boolean(RUN_OUTPUT) != false) {
        document.getElementsByClassName("errorField").textContent = "";

        runOutputForm(div, name, address, city, fullState, zip,
            email, areaCode, prefix, suffix, genderChoice,
            courseChoice);
    }
}

function runOutputForm(div, name, address, city, fullState, zip,
                       email, areaCode, prefix, suffix, genderChoice,
                       courseChoice) {

    function br() {
        return document.createElement('br');
    }

    var printName = document.createTextNode("Name: " + name + " ");
    var printEmail = document.createTextNode("Email: " + email + " ");
    var printPhone = document.createTextNode("Phone: " + areaCode + "-" + prefix + "-" + suffix);
    var printAddress = document.createTextNode("Address: " + address + " " + city + ", " + fullState.text + " " + zip);
    var printGender = document.createTextNode("Gender: " + genderChoice);
    var printCourses = document.createTextNode("Courses Taken: " + courseChoice + " ");

    div.appendChild(br());
    div.appendChild(printName);
    div.appendChild(br());
    div.appendChild(printEmail);
    div.appendChild(br());
    div.appendChild(printPhone);
    div.appendChild(br());
    div.appendChild(printAddress);
    div.appendChild(br());
    div.appendChild(printGender);
    div.appendChild(br());
    div.appendChild(printCourses);
    div.appendChild(br());

    var output = document.getElementById("output");

    if (output) {
        output.parentNode.replaceChild(div, output);
    } else {
        document.body.appendChild(div);
    }
}
```

I would like for only the current accurate messages to appear, either errors or valid output, not both. My element-replacing logic seems to be off. I am not using jQuery or innerHTML for this project. Please advise.

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p1dj36r5/)

Comment: Why are you not using `innerHTML`?

Comment: part of the specs for this project. I understand it would be a hell of a lot easier that way though.